# Editing of a table using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following problem:

A company is testing composite samples. In one table the information of the sample is added. On a second table("Test Results")  at first only the SampleID number will appear. The sample is sent to the lab and after 4 months the test results are received. The secretary now has to update the table "Test results". So she goes to her Userform Types in The sampleID and all relevant data fields. She clicks update table.

The program now automatically searches in test results for the sample ID and edits allcolumns of that row with the data.

My code looks like this:

```
 Dim lstObj As ListObject
Dim objNewRow As ListRow
Dim i As Integer
Dim ID As ListObject
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim tRows As Long
Dim tCols As Long


Set Obj = Worksheets("Tests Results").ListObjects("Test_results")

'count rows
Set tbl = Worksheets("Tests Results").ListObjects("Test_results")
With tbl.DataBodyRange
    tRows = .Rows.Count
End With




For i = 1 To tRows

If Obj = Me.sampleID.Value Then

Set objNewRow = lstObj.ListRows.Change(AlwaysInsert:=True)

With Obj
    .ListColumns("Test Lab").DataBodyRange(x) = Me.ComboBox_LAB.Value
    .ListColumns("Flammability Type ").DataBodyRange(x) = Me.ComboBoxFlamm.Value
    .ListColumns("Avg-Smoke Density Pass Value (Ds)").DataBodyRange(x) = Me.ComboBoxSDpass.Value
    .ListColumns("Maximum Smoke Density Pass Value_Flaming_ (DS)").DataBodyRange(x) = Me.ComboBoxMAXSD.Value
    .ListColumns("Smoke Density Mode").DataBodyRange(x) = Me.ComboBoxSmoke.Value
end with
End If
End For
```

Comment: so what's your issue? state it along with all its relevant details and some data examples as well

Comment: Please note that the first part is done already. I only need to do the table editing. The Issue is that I cannot edit the table.Data Samples: A0225 25 14 , Where the first set of digits is the sampleID, the second is the yield strength and the last one is the burn time.

Comment: so what's your code for the second part and where does it fail?

Comment: Let me rephrase my question: How do I loop through the first column of a table? If the value in the cell equals the sampleID then edit the table row?

Comment: Just google "vba excel how to loop through table columns"

Comment: I have changed to the find function. But now I get the error 438 “Object does not support this property or method” The code:                     Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim Obj As Range

Set Obj = Worksheets("Tests Results").ListObjects("Test_results").Find(SampleID.Value)

 
With Obj
    .ListColumns("Test Lab") = Me.ComboBox_LAB.Value